# 404 - Http the requested is not available JavaEE Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

No estoy muy familiarizado con Spring MVC DriverManagerDataSource. Estoy tratando de devolver un JSP desde mi controlador. El método de mi controlador funciona bien, pero al devolver la vista, aparece un error 404.

No sé por qué recibí este error si tengo esto en el web.xml:

---

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

---

spring-servlet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation = 
    "
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    "> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="controllers"></context:component-scan> <!-- com.javatpoint. -->
    
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">    
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>    
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>    
    </bean>   
    
    <bean class = "org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name = "driverClassName" value = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name = "url" value = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/empleados"></property>
        <property name = "username" value = "---"></property>
        <property name = "password" value = "---"></property>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="jt" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">    
        <property name="dataSource" ref="ds"></property>    
    </bean> 
    
    <bean id = "dao" class = "dao.EmpDao">
        <property name = "template" ref = "jt"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    <display-name>SpringMVC</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

HomeController.java

```
package EjemploCRUD.SpringMVC.controller;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public ModelAndView test(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
        return new ModelAndView("index");
    }
}
```

MvcConfiguration.java

```
package EjemploCRUD.SpringMVC.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="EjemploCRUD.SpringMVC")
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    
}
```

Error

```
Type Status Report

Message The requested resource [/SpringMVC/] is not available

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

Answer (score 0):

En ningún lugar tienes especificada una ruta "/SpringMVC/", en todas partes tienes configurado solo "/".

De cualquier manera, a menos que tengas algún motivo en particular, para este tipo de cosas te recomiendo usar Spring Boot con el módulo web, y te ahorras todas estas configuraciones. http://start.springboot.io y puedes generar una aplicación base en 10 segundos.

Comment: Es lo que se me hacía raro, al correrlo me mandaba a esa URL, pero solo dejaba el "/" y de igual manera me marcaba el mismo error para "/", pero checar el link que me mencionas!, gracias!